# Why does Spark Query Plan shows more partitions whenever cache (persist) is used

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Given this PySpark code on a single worker Spark cluster with 2 cores:

```
df = spark.table('table')

df = df.dropDuplicates(['checksum'])

#
df = df.cache()

...

df.write.save('...)
```

it generates and executes a plan with 200 partitions when cache is present and only 2 partitions when `df.cache()` is not present.

I am particularly interested to know the impact cache has on the planning in this case.

With cache:
[image: with df.cache]

Without cache:
[image: without cache]

A similar impact `df.cache` seems to have on AQE(Adaptive Query Execution), coalescing post shuffle partitions doesn't seem to occur if the DataFrame is cached after an expensive shuffle.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It seems like a bug.

Comment: @Constantine thats true, it was a bug or maybe lets call it better "analysis gap" but it was fixed, i added my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats a really nice question!

I digged in, and i can confirm that by default Spark with AQE behaves like you described. Relation which is cached is not optimized by AQE.

This was addressed in this ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-35332

Outcome of this ticket is that this was changed and now we can set spark.sql.optimizer.canChangeCachedPlanOutputPartitioning to true to allow AQE to change paritioning during caching

I did a test on Databricks cluster with Spark 3.2

Sample code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.optimizer.canChangeCachedPlanOutputPartitioning", false)

val data = Seq(("1", "Frankfurt am main", "Germany"),("1", "Frankfurt am main", "Germany"))
val df = data.toDF("Id", "City", "Country")
val uniqueRecords = df.dropDuplicates("City").cache()
uniqueRecords.show()
```

With default setting i had this stages:

[image]

Physical plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit (9)
+- InMemoryTableScan (1)
      +- InMemoryRelation (2)
            +- SortAggregate (8)
               +- Sort (7)
                  +- Exchange (6)
                     +- SortAggregate (5)
                        +- * Sort (4)
                           +- * LocalTableScan (3)
```

As you can see, no AQE at all

Now lets try with

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.optimizer.canChangeCachedPlanOutputPartitioning", true)
```

Stages:

[image]

And physical plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit (10)
+- InMemoryTableScan (1)
      +- InMemoryRelation (2)
            +- AdaptiveSparkPlan (9)
               +- SortAggregate (8)
                  +- Sort (7)
                     +- Exchange (6)
                        +- SortAggregate (5)
                           +- Sort (4)
                              +- LocalTableScan (3)
```

So i can cofirm that it works when you change this parameter on Spark 3.2 and above. AQE is visible in plan and partitions are coalesced

Answer (score 1):

This is an effect of AQE. See the Custom Shuffle Reader node in your 2nd image.

"...it executes CustomShuffleReaderExec instead of the ShuffleExchangeExec and the ShuffledRowRDD is executed with map-based shuffle files that should already be present in the local block manager (hence local shuffle reader)"
https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-sql/what-new-apache-spark-3-local-shuffle-reader/read

The 200 partitions is from the default value of config spark.sql.shuffle.partitions

Comment: I understand that AQE stepped-in and optimised the shuffle (caused by the dropDuplicates) but its not clear why it didn't do the same when the `df.cache` call is present ?